# Video not auto playing when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, button, video

I have two questions i wondered if anyone could help me with. The first is specific, the second is more general advice. I appreciate that my second question is very long and quite broad so not expecting many people to answer or read that one.

1. I'm trying to get the videos to autoplay when clicked, using the below html / js. The initial video "videos/vid1.mov" auto plays when i open the browser but when i click any of the buttons the videos don't auto play. Any ideas where i'm going wrong?
2. I'm starting a website project, where i want people to create there own relaxation soundscape. Eg a webpage where there is an image of cozy little cabin (taking up most of the page), with a large window pane. The user can click various buttons to change the background scene in the window (eg changing a raining video to a video of heavy snow). They could also click a button to turn on the fire etc. The user will also be able to change the intensity of sounds. I'd class myself as a relative beginner with very some basic html and css knowledge, so i'm pretty much going to learn as i go through trial and error. My basic idea at the moment is to try overlay an image onto the video, with various bits of the image being transparent (ie the windows) so some of the video will show through. Know idea how i'll do this yet. Just wondered if anyone has any pointers in terms of whether this general direction is good, or whether there is any other approach which i should research. It would be nice if the site could also be mobile friendly also. Hopefully this question makes sense!

JS

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    function changevid(buttonlink) {

    document.getElementById('change').src = buttonlink;

    }

    </script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<h1> Create your own personalised soundscape!</h1>


        <button onClick="changevid('videos/vid1.mov')">Video 1</button>
        <button onClick="changevid('videos/vid2.mp4')">Video 2</button>
        <button onClick="changevid('videos/vid3.mp4')">Video 3</button>

<video controls autoplay loop id="change">
  <source src="videos/vid1.mov" type="video/mp4"></source>

</video>

</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, check the path!

[image]